# Socket Keepalive with Periodic Send

Tags: sockets

I have a C/C++ application set up as follows:

- A non-blocking TCP server socket on a linux platform
- A thread which writes a small packet (less than 20 bytes) to the socket at 1 Hz
- The socket is configured with `keepalive` enabled and with: `keepidle`=5, `keepintvl`=5 and `keepcnt`=3

My intention is that the `keepalive` mechanism should detect a physical disconnection of the network link. However, when the link is cut, I do not see the zero-length packets which should be generated by the `keepalive` mechanism (I am using tcpdump to monitor traffic). My impression is that what happens is this: after the cable disconnection, the application keeps making send requests and the fact that there are pending send requests prevents the keepalive mechanism from being activated. Is this explanation valid?

In order to check my explanation, I have modified my test as follows:

- A non-blocking TCP server socket on a linux platform
- A cyclical thread which writes a small packet (about 100 bytes) to the socket with a period of 30 seconds
- The socket is configured with `keepalive` enabled and with: `keepidle`=5, `keepintvl`=5 and `keepcnt`=2

In this case, if I cut the connection, the keepalive mechanism triggers within about 15-20 seconds (which is what I would expect).

On a related point, I would like to understand the exact semantics of `tcp_keepidle`. This is defined as: "The number of seconds a connection needs to be idle before TCP begins sending out keep-alive probes". What exactly does 'idle' means in this context? Does it simply mean that nothing is received and nothing is put on the network; or does it mean that nothing is received and no send requests are made to the socket?